# MySQL: Adding column to query that summarises sequential data from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update, gaps-and-islands

I have two tables. Table 1 is a list of items and IDs and table 2 is a list of sales data where each row shows the sales for a specific item for a specific week:

Table 1: Items

```
ITEM NAME        ITEM ID  
Item1  item1_id  
Item2   item2_id  
Item3   item3_id  
....
```

and

Table 2: Sales Data

```
ITEM  WEEK  SALES  
Item1 1 3  
Item1 2 5  
Item1 3 4  
Item2 2 5  
Item2 3 6  
....
```

I am looking to do is create a column in my output that documents the number of weeks of sequential sales (NUM_Sales). The result for this example would be

```
ITEM NAME ITEM ID NUM_Sales  
Item1 item1_id 3  
Item2 item2_id 2
```

As Item1 has sales in weeks 1,2,3 (so 3 sequential weeks) while Item2 only has sales in weeks 2,3 (so 2 sequential weeks)

I'm very new to MySQL so have never done anything this complex and am not sure where to start. How can I write a query to do this?

Comment: If `item1` has weeks 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, what would be the result?

Comment: @GMB in that case it would be 3 as only the last three weeks are sequential (4,5,6)

Comment: This is a Gaps & Islands problem. It can be resolved with window frames. Those are available in MySQL 8.x. Are you using MySQL 5.x or 8.x?

Comment: @TheImpaler Thank you for your response. I'm using a 5.x

Answer (score 1):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can solve this gaps-and-islands problem with window functions. The idea is to use the difference between `row_number()` and `week` to generate groups of adjacent records:

```
alter table items add column num_sales int;

update items i
inner join (
    select item, max(cnt) cnt
    from (
        select s.*, count(*) over(partition by item, week - rn) cnt
        from (
            select 
                s.*, 
                row_number() over(partition by item order by week) rn
                from sales_data s
        ) s
    ) s
    group by item
) s on s.item = i.item
set i.num_sales = s.cnt
```

Comment: Ah... cool. This solution would be simpler than mine since it doesn't use window frames.  Even though the OP has MySQL 5.x I'm upvoting it.

Comment: @TheImpaler: thanks! I think this wil be very tedious to solve in MySQL < 8.0...

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the first week in the last sequence as:

```
select s.item_id,
       max(s.week) as last_week,
       max(case when sprev.week is null then week end) as first_week,
       (max(s.week) - max(case when sprev.week is null then week end) + 1) as num_weeks
from sales s left join
     sales sprev
     on sprev.item_id = s.item_id and sprev.week = s.week
group by s.item_id;
```

You can incorporate this into an `update` as:

```
update items i join
       (select s.item_id,
               max(s.week) as last_week,
               max(case when sprev.week is null then week end) as first_week,
               (max(s.week) - max(case when sprev.week is null then week end) + 1) as num_weeks
        from sales s left join
             sales sprev
             on sprev.item_id = s.item_id and sprev.week = s.week
        group by s.item_id
       ) iw
       on iw.item_id = i.item_id
    set num_sales = iw.num_weeks;
```

This is slightly more concise in MySQL 8+ -- using `lag()` instead of the self join.  With the right indexing -- `sales(item_id, week)` -- the performance on this might even be faster than the window function.